# Implement one-to-many relationship with an array of ids?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, many-to-many, one-to-many

Is it a good idea to store like 0-1000 of chapters ids in array in Book table and select them from chapters table like this:

```
SELECT id, name, updated FROM chapters
WHERE id IN (SELECT unnest(chapters_array) FROM books WHERE id=$1);
```

Or it's better to make separate table and store there `chapter_id` to `book_id` relations?

Comment: It is a bad idea as it breaks first normal form of relational databases. Make a chapter table with a foreign key to the book table's primary key. You don't want to store multiple data points within one field if you can help it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: This is (obviously) a(n easily found) faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Besides breaking normal form and introducing a host of problems, it also seems uncalled for in your case. A book has *n* chapters. And a chapter always belongs to a *single* book. That's a plain 1:n relationship like you mentioned in title yourself! You don't need a *"separate table"*. All you need is the ID of the book in each related row of the `chapters` table. Like:

```
CREATE TABLE chapters
  id serial PRIMARY KEY
, book_id int REFERENCES books(id) -- !
, name text NOT NULL
, updated timestamptz
);
```

I added a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint with short syntax. [Details in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) (That's also something you couldn't use with an array.)

Then your query to get all chapters of a given book can simply be:

```
SELECT id, name, updated
FROM   chapters
WHERE  book_id = $1;
```

While you don't want anything from the `books` table, you don't even have to include it in the query. The FK constraints enforces referential integrity anyway.